# cant' establish websocket connection on every pair on Binance exchange.Io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket error

Tags: java, websocket, binance

My aplication's logic requires websocet connection for every pair on Binance exchange.

[I use this library](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api)

I use three methods to receive data from exchange:

> 1.onAggTradeEvent
>
> 2.onAllMarketTickersEvent
>
> 3. onDepthEvent

I create only one instance of BinanceApiWebSocketClient class and i call methods described above in separate threads. This is my code:

```
pairs().stream().forEach(pair->{
            wsClient.onDepthEvent(symboltoLowerCase(),orderBookCallback());
        });
pairs().stream().forEach(pair->{
            wsClient.onAggTradeEvent(symbol.toLowerCase(), tradesCallback());
        });
pairs().stream().forEach(pair->{
wsClient.onAllMarketTickersEvent(tickers -> {//some logic here});
        });
```

When i run this code some time it's work but then websockets close without any errors.
When i searched solution for my issue i find that not only i encounter with this problem and i write custom client for Binance exchange using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) based on this [code](https://github.com/eugene-kamenev/binance-better-websocket)

I initialize http client this way:

```
private AsyncHttpClient client;

    public BinanceWebSocketCustomClient() {
        this.client = HttpUtils.newAsyncHttpClient(new DefaultEventLoopGroup(1000),100,1000);
    }
```

I create websocket as follow:

```
private Closeable createNewWebSocket(String channel, BinanceWebsocetListener listener){
       String streamingUrl = String.format("%s/%s", BinanceApiConstants.WS_API_BASE_URL, channel);
       AtomicReference<NettyWebSocket> websocetReference = new AtomicReference<>();
       try {
           NettyWebSocket nettyWebSocket = client.prepareGet(streamingUrl).execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder()
                   .addWebSocketListener(listener).build()).get();
           websocetReference.set(nettyWebSocket);
       } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
           LOG.error("create new websocet",e);
       }
       return () -> {
           final int code = 1000;
           listener.onClose(websocetReference.get(),code,null);
           websocetReference.get().onClose(1000,null);
       };
   }
```

I reuse binance library callback methods

```
public Closeable onAggTradeEvent(String symbol, BinanceApiCallback<AggTradeEvent> callback) {
        final String channel = String.format("%s@aggTrade", symbol);
        return createNewWebSocket(channel, new BinanceWebsocetListener<>(callback, AggTradeEvent.class));
    }
```

But when i run this code i recieve error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Could not initialize class
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket    at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:179)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:108)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:33)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:435)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:248)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket    at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel.(EpollSocketChannel.java:45)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.EpollSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(EpollSocketChannelFactory.java:23)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.EpollSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(EpollSocketChannelFactory.java:19)
>     at
>   io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:320)
>     at
>   io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:163)
>     at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:156)     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:81)
>     ... 77 common frames omitted ERROR BinanceWebSocetCustomClient
>   [BinanceWebSocetCustomClient.java:68] create new websocet
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Could not initialize class io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:202)
>     at
>   exchange.binance.BinanceWebSocetCustomClient.createNewWebSocket(BinanceWebSocetCustomClient.java:65)
>     at
>   exchange.binance.BinanceWebSocetCustomClient.onAggTradeEvent(BinanceWebSocetCustomClient.java:48)
>     at exchange.Exchange.main(Exchange.java:74) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Could not initialize class
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket    at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:179)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:108)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:162)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:82)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect(NettyChannelConnector.java:69)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:106)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:33)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:435)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:248)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket    at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel.(EpollSocketChannel.java:45)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.EpollSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(EpollSocketChannelFactory.java:23)
>     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.EpollSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(EpollSocketChannelFactory.java:19)
>     at
>   io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:320)
>     at
>   io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:163)
>     at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:156)     at
>   org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector.connect0(NettyChannelConnector.java:81)
>     ... 77 common frames omitted

Maybe i config http client unproper way?

Comment: From the error message I can say than Initialization of class io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket has failed. Reason should be somewhere down the stack trace. Could you post whole stack trace?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help. I've updated a question.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket`
This message means that class initialization has failed earlier during program execution. You need to find very first exception which contains actual reason why class initialization has failed. Try to search logs for ExceptionInInitializerError.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've found that i have repeated dependencies and thus classloader can't initialize LinuxSocket.class .

Comment: Maybe this project helpful using biance websocket https://github.com/namjug-kim/reactive-crypto